# Is there a way to get the img size from this js and apply it this jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I'm working inside a program that has an old js pop up and I'm trying get it into a jQuery modal window, the problem I'm having is getting the img size.

This is the [24hr DEMO](http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite367039/website/)

The original script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    function newWin(strURL,imgheight,imgwidth) {
    var mybar='toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no';
    mybar+=',width=';
    mybar+=imgwidth;
    mybar+=',height=';
    mybar+=imgheight;

    window.open(strURL, 'newWin', mybar);
  }
//-->
</script>
```

..and the HTML get's written like this:

```
<div id="TMBOBJ7DD361E59F1760" style=" position:absolute; top:201px; left:79px; width:150px; height:96px;  z-index:4;" >
<a href="nextpop/imag001A.html" onclick="newWin('nextpop/imag001A.html',408,630);return false;" target="_blank">
<img src="nextpop/imag001.jpg" width=150 height=96 border=0 alt="Mustang">
</a>
</div>
```

Now I have it so it all converts with this jQuery as you can see in the DEMO

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('[id^=TMBOBJ]').each(function() {
var $a = $(this).find('a');
$a.attr('href' , $a.attr('href').replace('html', 'jpg' ));
$a.removeAttr('onclick');
$a.removeAttr('target');
});

$(function () {
var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - $("#large")[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - $("#large")[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
$("#large").css('top', top + "px");
$("#large").css('left', left + "px");
$("#large").css('position', 'fixed');
});

$('#background').each(function() {
$(this).css('height',$(document).height());
$(this).css('width',$(document).width());
});

$('[id^=TMBOBJ] img').click(function(){

$("#background").css({"opacity" : "0.7"})
.fadeIn("slow");

$("#large").html("<img src='"+$(this).parent().attr("href")+"' alt='"+$(this).attr("alt")+"' /><br/>"+$(this).attr("alt")+"")
.fadeIn("slow");
return false;
});

$("#background").click(function(){
$("#background").fadeOut("slow");
$("#large").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#large").click(function(){
$("#background").fadeOut("slow");
$("#large").fadeOut("slow");
});

});
```

Except I can't figure out how to get the img size any ideas it's a tough one for a beginner like me. I tried this:

```
$("img").load(function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('[id^=TMBOBJ]'); 
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
});
```

But I need to get the size out of the original script is what I'm thinking?
I know... but it'll help update the wysiwyg program for folks and I am close *(it's proved to be an interesting problem too geting this far)*.

Comment: Are you trying to **set** the image size and image height? Or get it? What do you wish to do with the values?

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('[id^=TMBOBJ]');` is an issue/won't work as it expects an `ID`, not a query selector.

Either make it a jQuery selector:

```
var img = $('[id^=TMBOBJ]');
```

or use **document.querySelectorAll()**

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=TMBOBJ]')
```

Worth nothing that both of these selectors will return an array of DOM elements, so your load function should be modified, or simply use `$(this)` for your scope.

Also, use jQuery to its full potential!

- [jQuery's `$(this)` demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)
- [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)
- [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

```
$("img").load(function(){
    var img = $(this),
        width = img.outerWidth(true),
        height = img.outerHeight(true);
});
```

Comment: The demo showed the problem the generated DOM doesn't get the large image size from the href so I'll have to figure something else out. I appreciate the look. I probably just didn't explain it properly.